# Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'Marker'. Property '_objectInstance' is missing in type 'Promise<void>'. Ionic 2

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2

I tried to apply what is in the docs gor the google maps in ionic 2 as it is in the official site: [Ionic Docs Google Maps](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/)

I got this error:

```
Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'Marker'. Property '_objectInstance' is missing in type 'Promise<void>'. Ionic 2
```

as it is figured in the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: what happens if you just declare it as any: `const marker: any = map...`?

Comment: khaled i need to speek to you tobee.dev@gmail.com.

Comment: i need ionic 2 developer, arabic one ^_^

Answer (score 3):

I had this error too, and the solution i've found is to not use marker variable, but only write

```
map.addMarker(markerOptions).then(...)
```

And it works, my marker was displayed.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 map.addMarker(markerOptions)
   .then((marker: Marker) => {
     marker.showInfoWindow();
   });
```

instead of

```
 const marker: Marker = map.addMarker(markerOptions)
   .then((marker: Marker) => {
     marker.showInfoWindow();
   });
```